# Not start a new page with scanty number of words, lines

Tags: page-breaking

This script

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[6][1-2]
\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image]

How can I avoid starting page 2 with such a scanty number of words, lines?

Answer (score 3):

You can use TeX's `\looseness` parameter. If you say `\looseness=<number>` for a paragraph, TeX will try to make it `<number>` lines longer than what would have been done otherwise, without exceeding the current `\tolerance`. `<number>` may be negative, so in your case, setting `\looseness=-1` for one of the paragraphs does the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\looseness=-1 % make the next paragraph one line shorter than usual
\lipsum[1-5]

\lipsum[6][1-2]
\end{document}
```

According to the TeXbook, `\looseness` is reset to zero at the same time as `\hangindent`, `\hangafter`, and `\parshape` are reset to their normal values, which is

> at the end of every paragraph, and (by local definitions) whenever it
>   enters internal vertical mode.

(TeXbook p. 103)

Therefore, the `\looseness=-1` in the above example affects only the first of the five paragraphs produced by `\lipsum[1-5]`. There is *no need* to do this assignment in a group.

If I remember correctly, the TeXbook also mentions a trick to spread some looseness among several paragraphs. I could probably find it if you're interested.

As suggested in [Skillmon's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483402/not-start-a-new-page-with-scanty-number-of-words-lines/483408#comment1222127_483402), another way would be to play with penalties, in particular with `\widowpenalty` (to avoid page breaking before the last line of a paragraph) and `\linepenalty` (to make TeX's line breaking algorithm more reluctant to add lines to a paragraph: this penalty defines the “base cost” of each line).